# How to efficiently write System.Array to a binary file in IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, binaryfiles, system.array

I have to write a `System.Array` (1e09 items from type Single) to a binary file. I could of course loop over the Array with `.GetValue()` and pack each Single in a 4-Byte struct, but this is very slow.

Is it possible to use the standard Python file i/o in this case? I have tried `somefile_write(some_systemarray)`, but this results in an error message.

I am mainly interested in 1D arrays, however an answer which works for nD arrays  would be highly appreciated.

**Edit** After reading the first comment, I have tried the following code:

```
    from System import *
    from System.IO import *

    arr = Array.CreateInstance(Single, 1e8)
    b = BinaryWriter(File.Open('test.bin', FileMode.Create))
    for i in arr :
       b.Write(i)
    b.Close()
```

Unfortunately, this takes appr. 45 sec. There is `BinaryWriter.Write(Byte[])` available. However, this will only speed up things when it is possible to convert `System.Array` to `Byte[]` quickly.

Comment: I suspect that [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), directly writing the stream or looking at [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(VS.71).aspx) might help. It seems unlikely that a "native python" operation on IronPython will be faster than anything .NET has to offer. What will happen to the data on the other end?

Comment: I will have a look into that. I would like to read the data from file in my C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an array of Byte instead of an array of Single?

```
from System import *
from System.IO import *

arr = Array.CreateInstance(Byte, 1e8)
b = BinaryWriter(File.Open('test.bin', FileMode.Create))
b.Write(arr)
b.Close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately the type is array of Single. As I am reading the data from an external API, I cannot change this.